# What is the SPE equivalent of "Revert Tree"?

Tags: powershell-extensions

What is the SPE equivalent of "Revert Tree"?

I've attempted the following:

```bsh
$config = [Sitecore.Configuration.Factory]::GetConfiguration();
$dataFolderPath = ($config.sitecore."sc.variable" | ?{ $_.name -eq 'dataFolder'}).Value
$serializationPath = "$dataFolderPath/serialization/master$($MyBucket.ItemPath)"

...

if(test-path "$serializationpath.item") {
    # restore the empty folder to delete children (~10,000) as a side-effect
    deserialize-item -path $serializationPath -root "$dataFolderPath/serialization/" -ForceUpdate -DisableEvents
}
```

.
But this does not seem to do the same thing as the button. The documentation doesn't reference this use case at all. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Having a look at the source code for `Import-Item` it appears that "revert" is tied to the "ForceUpdate" switch. The "Recurse" switch indicates that a tree should be loaded rather than just the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deserialize-item` command requires 2 parameters -

1. **path** - which is a path to the item on the drive but without `.item` extension. If the item does not exist in the Sitecore tree yet, you need to pass the parent item path.
2. **root** - the directory which is the root of serialization. **The trailing slash \ character is required**

In your case, you want to deserialize tree so `-Recurse` option is also **required**.

- You are passing both the parameter in your script but `$dataFolderPath` value may not have a full path from config if it is set to `/app_data`. Try to do a `write-host` for the path to make sure it is a full file path.
- try to use slash `\` character in the path not `/`
- Make sure `$serializationPath` value is correct with `$dataFolderPath` and `$MyBucket`

A sample script will be like this -

```
//serialization item path without .item extension
$serializationPath = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\yourwebsite\App_Data\serialization\master\sitecore\content\Global Settings\Topics"
//root file path of serialization
$rootPath = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\yourwebsite\App_Data\serialization\"
if(test-path "$serializationpath.item") {
deserialize-item -path $serializationPath -root $rootPath -ForceUpdate -DisableEvents -Recurse
}
```

Comment: In this case i looks like my issue was a combination of '/' and the missing `-recurse` flag. With just the recurse flag I was receiving errors, but with both in place the script works as desired